# Calculate and summarize total distance in a table using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table consists of user, sequence, and geolocation: x and y

I would like to group it by user and calculate total distance based on the sequence

For example:

```
> df <- data.frame(user_id=rep(1,3), seq=1:3, x=c(1,5,3), y=c(2,3,9))
> df
  user_id seq x y
1       1   1 1 2
2       1   2 5 3
3       1   3 3 9
```

Here is the function to calculate distance between two points (Euclidean):

```
> d <- function(n1,n2){
+   d <- sqrt((df$y[n2]-df$y[n1])^2+(df$x[n2]-df$x[n1])^2)
+   return(d)
+ }
```

I would like to get the total distance like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(user_id=1, dtot=d(1,2)+d(2,3))
> df
  user_id  dtot
1       1 10.45
```

How can I use dplyr "group_by" and get total distance based on the sequence for all users?

Comment: Your distance function receives two entries. On which two points should it calculate? does the sequence represent the point along the trajectory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you want is to define a function for computing the total distance:

```
library(dplyr)
total.dist <- function(x,y) {
  sum(sqrt((x-lag(x))^2+(y-lag(y))^2),na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

The inputs to this function are the column vectors `x` and `y`. We compute the distance between each row in vectorized fashion by subtracting with the `lag` of these columns. Then the total distance is the `sum` of all the distances computed, removing `NA`s.

Then using this as a `summarise` function `group_by` `user_id`:

```
res <- df %>% group_by(user_id) %>% summarise(dtot=total.dist(x,y))
### A tibble: 1 x 2
##  user_id     dtot
##    <dbl>    <dbl>
##1       1 10.44766
```